# Get list of all categories and subcategories in custom admin module

Tags: list, categories, admin, magento-1.9

I have used below code but it always return count 0.

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
echo count($_categories);
```

This is because this is not working for admin side modules, any other way for this?

Comment: Please check is `categories` are active or not.

Comment: All the categories are active and working fine when use category collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code to load all categories

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
count($categories);
```

Comment: To be more helpful, perhaps you could explain why the provided code works?

Comment: I edited code - check again. code load all categories from model